# User Profile Import Failing

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a SharePoint 2007 farm (SP2, June Cumulative Update) where the User Profile Import job is now failing.  The last log entry on the User Profile and Properties page shows the error message "The parameter is incorrect".  This persists whether the job is run manually or via the defined schedule.

What is interesting is that I see it working and running good in that I can see it successfully enumerating the AD profiles and the count goes up to the number I expect.  But...it appears that this data is not persisted as I have old accounts still showing up in "Active Profiles" but are no longer on Active Directory.  Also I can go to a test server and use the same settings for the import connection and user filter and it runs successfully.

Any ideas on what the problem might be or how to troubleshoot?  I have looked at all the logs but nothing has stood out so far and Google searches haven't turned up much on this topic.

Ryan

Comment: Have you tried increasing the logging level for the User Profile service to see if it logs a particular failure point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a case with Microsoft and after many hours we were unable to identify the issue inside the SSP that was the cause of the problem.  The next step was to build a new SSP and see if it had the problem and then migrate to that.  But I wasn't comfortable with the risk involved with that so for now we're just going to "live with it".  The impact of the problem currently seems only to affect the cleanup job for old profiles and My Sites where people have left the company.  Basically it never does any cleanup...but...I can easily create a custom job to handle that function so not a huge deal in the grand scheme of things.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added any custom profile properties and then tried mapping them to AD?

Comment: Sam, thanks for responding.  Yes I have added 5 additional columns of type string that are mapped to AD fields.  Do you think this error could be caused by something with custom fields?

Comment: Sam, also I have a test server with MOSS that is having the same problem.  It is on the same domain.  This server does not have any custom profile properties.  The crawl log shows one error as follows -

spsimport://myths
The parameter is incorrect.

Note MYTHS is my domain name.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Ryan, is your import working on either test or production? I would imagine that the incorrectly mapped fields would just produce errors, but not stop the import.

Have you tried clearing all accounts from your production site (not sure if this is a bit dangerous for your situation)?